# RSpec test method is called on `main` object

Tags: ruby, rspec

Sometimes we call methods on the ruby `main` objects. For example we call `create` for FactoryBot and we call `_()` for I18n.

What's a proper way to test these top level methods got called in RSpec?

For example, I want to test `N_` is called, but it would not work because the self in Rspec and self in the file are different.

```
# spec
describe 'unfound_translations' do
  it 'includes dynamic translations' do
    expect(self).to receive(:N_)
    load '/path/to/unfound_translations.rb')
  end
end

# unfound_translations.rb
N_('foo')
```

However this does not pass.

Comment: Hold on! How is it supposed to pass if you call `_N` outside of `it` block?

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. The example I gave does not work.

Comment: I *think* I understand the question, but please provide a [mcve]. A *minimal* example should not contain anything like `load Rails.root.join('locale/unfound_translations.rb')`, and a *complete, verifiable* example should be an actual reproduction of the problem.

Comment: @lulalala Are you going to fix or close your question?

Comment: @meta I edited my question when Tom mentioned it. However `load` is essentially what I need (I need to repeatedly load that file in order to perform different tests) so it is still there.

Comment: is the `_N('foo')` really the only thing in this file??

Comment: @meta yes, this is a convention of gettext_i18n_rails https://github.com/grosser/gettext_i18n_rails#unfound-translations-with-rake-gettextfind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I get your problem now. Your main issue is that `self` in `it` block is different that `self` inside `unfound_translations.rb`. So you're setting expectations on one object and method `N_` is called on something completely different.

(Edit: I just realized, when reading the subject of this question again, that you already was aware of it. Sorry for stating the obvious... leaving it so it may be useful to others)

I managed to have a hacky way that is working, here it is:

```
# missing_translations.rb
N_('foo')
```

and the spec (I defined a simple module for tests inside it for simplicity):

```
module N
  def N_(what)
    puts what
  end
end

RSpec.describe 'foo' do
  let(:klass) do
    Class.new do
      extend N
    end
  end

  it do
    expect(klass).to receive(:N_)
    klass.class_eval do
      eval(File.read('missing_translations.rb'))
    end
  end
end
```

What it does it's creating an anonymous class that. And evaluating contents of  `missing_translations.rb` inside means that `klass` is the `thing` that receives `N_` method. So you can set expectations there.

I'm pretty sure you can replace `extend N` module with whatever module is giving you `N_` method and this should work.

It's hacky, but not much effort so maybe good enough until more elegant solution is provided.

Comment: thanks, I was also thinking `eval` as last resort. Would still be nice if somehow I can obtain the main object :P

Comment: There's also [Kernel#binding](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-binding) but this also is to be used with `eval`.